# python, how to tell what type of obj was returned

Tags: python, types

How can i find out if the obj returned by a func is a int or something else (like a sqlite cursor)

Comment: Why would you ever need to know this?  Please provide some context in which you're trying to figure out the type.  Perhaps an overview of the code you'd like to write.

Comment: There are certainly valid reasons to check an object's type in Python. A code sample never hurts, of course.

Comment: @David - type checking is often a clumsy mistake better solved by polymorphism.  Code samples can help provide a better solution that avoids type checking entirely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `isinstance(item, type)` -- for instance:

```
if isinstance(foo, int):
    pass # handle this case
```

However, explicit type checking is not considered a good practice in the Python world -- it means that much of the power of duck typing is lost: Something which walks and quacks like a duck should be allowed to be a duck, even if it isn't! :)

Comment: It's called isinstance() in Python

Comment: Yup, caught that myself -- was fixing it as you replied.

Answer (score -1):

Use the built-in "type" function, e.g. type(10) -> .

Comment: Using type() to check equality means that instances of a subclass aren't recognized, so it's not usually the Right Thing.

Comment: Well, usually yes. Very occasionally you do still want type()... difficult to call without any context though. I don't know of any API that uses a variant that could be an int or SQLite cursor!

Comment: Yes, right, and I think that also points back to what Charles said, that using either "type" or "isinstance" is usually not considered good practice. There probably are valid uses, but you may want to think once more about what you are trying to do before actually using any of them.